# Handle database down in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to test on my system if the database is down with Spring Boot. I have written a rest call for testing. When the database is up, it return "test" which is correct result. But the database is down, it return nothing.
The Goal is to make it to return "test" even the database is down. Below is the error

```
2020-04-27 17:27:00.003 ERROR 9536     [] --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:450)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
        at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.cleanUpExpiredSessions(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:589)
        at org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.lambda$configureTasks$0(JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.java:194)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:262)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:56)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:162)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:400)
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 60000ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:669)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:183)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to X:X:X:X:xxxx refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:699)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:685)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

And the test controller is in below

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public String test() {
        System.out.println("test");
        return "Test";
    }

}
```

the `application.properties` is like below

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=50000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=60000
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=KlmsHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.initialization-fail-timeout= -1
spring.datasource.hikari.isolate-internal-queries=true
spring.datasource.hikari.allow-pool-suspension=true
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.test-on-return=false
spring.datasource.validation-interval=40000
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=5000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=5000
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned-timeout=3
spring.datasource.log-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.log-validation-errors=true


################### Hibernate Configuration ##########################
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean during the startup of Spring or while the application is running?

Your RestController currently does not access the DB so I fail to see how the DB connection could result in errors and if the DB is down the controller should return "Test".

If you mean during startup you can try:

`spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true`

Comment: I am not mean during startup. The application is up with your config. I would like to successfully return even the DB is down when it is started.

Comment: Just to be clear the following works for you:

1. DB is up and running
2. Your application is up and running
3. Rest call returns "test"


What is currently not working for you is the following:
1. DB is down
2. Although DB is down your application starts
3. But the rest call does not return "test"
Is that correct?

Comment: Or doesn't you application start although you have `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true` in your properties?

Comment: The situation is the first one, the application is up, and then the db is down, and the rest api is not working

Answer (score -1):

> Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster
>   is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Answer (score -1):

Cause of error if Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to X:X:X:X:xxxx refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Please make sure the database host and port in your application.properties file are mentioned and are correct and also the database instance is up and running in mentioned host.

Comment: But i would like to call the rest api successfully even though DB is down.